# IIS giving 503 error while using ApplicationPoolIdentity

Tags: iis

We are recently observing a very weird issue in IIS. This is the new ***Windows 2012 R2***. We have installed all the component of IIS and trying to host default website on port 80.

Whenever we are trying to access the default web page of IIS, I am seeing "HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable" error. While troubleshooting more, have observed that IIS Application pool is getting stopped and in the event logs we are seeing following error.
"**The identity of application pool DefaultAppPool is invalid. The user name or password that is specified for the identity may be incorrect, or the user may not have batch logon rights. If the identity is not corrected, the application pool will be disabled when the application pool receives it first request**"

DefaulAppPool identity is ***ApplicationPoolIdentity***.

As of now tried with following options but no luck. Note that same configuration is working on another server and I am unable to find out any difference on both the servers. ***IIS version is 8.5***

1. Logon batch rights provided to IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool as well as for IIS_IUSRS
2. Executed aspnet_regiis -ga "IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool" for .NET folders
3. Full rights of WebSite root directory to IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool
4. Reinstallation of IIS
5. Load User Profile : False / True with ApplicationPoolIdentity
6. Force update of Group policy post changin logon batch through gpupdate /force
7. Full Control to

   a) HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\

   b) HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\EnterpriseCertificates\

   c) HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\services\eventlog\Security\

   d) access to C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\AppData\

Do anyone have any idea in this?

Comment: You need everything documented in https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/981949/description-of-default-permissions-and-user-rights-for-iis-7-0-and-lat

Comment: I suggest you could try to modify the application pool identity to use local service or local system to check if this issue is related with the application pool identity permission.

Comment: @Lexli : Thanks I am checking that documentation.

Comment: @BrandoZhang: Correct I forgot to mentioned that in the description. If we change the identity to LocalSystem the website work without any issue. It seems to problem in ApplicationPoolIdentity.

Comment: @lexLi I have crossed checked my configuration with the provided doc. We have all the permission correctly. It seems that this particular server itself is an issue.